# Confused with BEM: How to address body element with BEM?

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

In my recent project I have scss file like so:

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: url('https://...jpg') bottom center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;

  h2 {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
  }
  [rest of code]
}
```

And now I'm trying to rewrite to BEM. I want to address whole body element. Maybe this is against BEM principles and I shouldn't do that?

Comment: You can always add a class to the body element.

Comment: @mpen So it is nothing wrong with doing like so:
<body class="body"> 
?

Comment: Not sure. I don't use BEM. I'd say if you want to style the body, go ahead and style the body; no class necessary. I think BEM is mostly a way for you to avoid naming collisions with your class names and keep organized, it's not to stop you from styling the elements you want to style.

Comment: @mpen is right but we usually add `page` class to `body` element to make it consistent with other selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<body class="body"></body>` is fine.

Actually usually for `body` tag in BEM is used class `"page"`. So You would have `<body class="page"></body>`.

It sounds greater because usually inside body we have then `<header class="header page__header"></header>` , `<main class="content page__content"></main>` and `<footer class="footer page__footer"></footer>`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!